# How can I implement an array in a struct and initialize it?

Tags: javascript, arrays, blockchain, ethereum, solidity

I'm having some trouble figuring out a problem in my code. Basically, I have a contract that represents games using structs. I store some details there like the gameId, required buyin to play, etc. But I also want to store player addresses that interact with that specific game: (in an array in the game struct, preferably).

I try to append them to the array on initialization but that doesn't work - I assume due to the static length of the array. I've read online about incrementing the length of the players array as they are not dynamic, but honestly I'm not sure how to implement that in this case.

Here is my code for the Game struct:

```
struct Game {
    address host; // Establishes host function access
    uint gameId; // Allows different games to be played concurrently
    uint buyinRequirement; // To establish minimum buyin amount for a game
    uint etherWithdrawalReqs; // Tracks # of ether in total from requests. If >/< than contract balance, throws error        
    uint gamePot; // Tracks how much ether is in the game's pot
    uint8 tableWithdrawalReqs; // Tracks how many players have requested a withdrawal
    uint8 playerCount; // Tracks # of of players in a game
    uint8 verifiedWithdrawalReqs; // Tracks # of verifs that withdrawal requests are valid
    bool endedBuyin; // Host function to end buyin stage
    address[] playerList; // Stores player addresses
}
```

Here is my attempt to initialize the struct:

```
function initializeGame(string memory name, uint buyinReq) public payable {
    idToGame[gameNumber] = Game(msg.sender, gameNumber, buyinReq, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, playerList.push(msg.sender));
    games.push(idToGame[gameNumber]);
}
```

This is the error I get:

```
    DeclarationError: Undeclared identifier.
   --> contracts/YourContract.sol:104:93:
    |
104 |         idToGame[gameNumber] = Game(msg.sender, gameNumber, buyinReq, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, playerList.push(msg.sender));
    |                                                                                             ^^^^^^^^^^

Error HH600: Compilation failed
```

Ultimately, I just need to track addresses tied to a specific game so I can render those addresses to the front end with some other information. If there is an easier way to do this and I'm just overlooking something due to tunnel vision, I'm all ears for alternative solutions.

### Edit

Shout out to 7Ony for the response!

Here is my code now:

```
function initializeGame(string memory name, uint buyinReq) public payable isNotInGame {     
    require(initFee == .001 ether, "In order to prevent spam games that never resolve, each game initialization will cost  ether.");
    playerInfo[msg.sender] = Player(name, gameNumber, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, true);
    address[] memory add;
    idToGame[gameNumber] = Game(msg.sender, gameNumber, buyinReq, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, true, add);
    idToGame[gameNumber].playerList.push(msg.sender);
    games.push(idToGame[gameNumber]);
    incGameNumber();
    addFeesPending();
}
```

There are no errors when I compile this code, however when I attempt to render the Game to my front end via ethersjs, it's like the array was never created:

```
0x59D101AD9DdeA84C0e11DA137000Dd91A0b20c79,1,1000000000000000000,0,1000000000000000000,0,1,0,false,true (cuts off the playerList array, which should be the very last element)
```

Console-logged output:

[Console-logged image of Game struct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TS1J2.png)

Am I doing something wrong here?

### Edit 2

Alright, here is my getter function:

```
function getPlayers(uint inputId) external returns (address[] memory playerList) {
    playerList = games[inputId].playerList;
}
```

As a reminder, playerList is the array I have located inside the Game struct and games holds those structs. As of now, this is what it looks like getPlayers is returning:

```
    {"type":2,"chainId":31337,"nonce":32,"maxPriorityFeePerGas":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x59682f00"},"maxFeePerGas":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x59b61d36"},"gasPrice":null,"gasLimit":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x6f8c"},"to":"0x9fE46736679d2D9a65F0992F2272dE9f3c7fa6e0","value":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x00"},"data":"0x460e20490000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000","accessList":[],"hash":"0x221b93ed95fdc65e07a340a8e099e0b8e3600a0b34538825462d7dbbff400a89","v":0,"r":"0xbb258e1b11ed29ea57b12c6336f73572f4bf7c7ad13415dc6af19895ff628b54","s":"0x0e09991ebb19abdc6359f847b35e74d3358d8d43460f9d5b55289d77f2745a5d","from":"0x59D101AD9DdeA84C0e11DA137000Dd91A0b20c79","confirmations":0}
```

In this instance, I had it so there should be both the account address of `0x59D101AD9DdeA84C0e11DA137000Dd91A0b20c79` and `0xd8098C8D6D474a8C7aA3eFa076C1695DcBc6DD4F` in the playerList, but neither show up.

Unless I am not seeing something that you are, the getter I retrofitted over from the previous question does not seem to be outputting what I expected it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that I haven't full visibility of your code (there's no reference to `idToGame` and `games` definitions), I assume that:

- `idToGame` is a `mapping(uint => Game)`
- `games` is a `Game[]`

This is the correct way to add a dynamic array, with an element inside:

1. initialize the dynamic array
2. assign it to the Game initialization
3. push elements into it

So your code should looks like

```
function initializeGame(string memory name, uint buyinReq) public payable {
    address[] memory add;
    idToGame[gameNumber] = Game(msg.sender, gameNumber, buyinReq, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, add);
    idToGame[gameNumber].playerList.push(msg.sender);
    games.push(idToGame[gameNumber]);
}
```

You can `push()` an item into an array only when a `Game` element is created (and saved in `storage`). In solidity the `push()`method is available only to `storage` variables, not in `memory` ones. The following snippet does **NOT** work due to this reason

```
function initializeGame(string memory name, uint buyinReq) public payable {
    address[] memory add;
    add.push(msg.sender);
    idToGame[gameNumber] = Game(msg.sender, gameNumber, buyinReq, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, add);
    games.push(idToGame[gameNumber]);
}
```

**Edit**
If you try to access you `playerList` array from `etherjs`, you need to implemet your getter. For reference, see: [Cannot retrieve uint Array from Struct in Solidity](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/118509/cannot-retrieve-uint-array-from-struct-in-solidity)

This is an example of how the getter should work for a single element

```
function getPlayerInGame(uint gameNumber, uint playerPos) external returns (address player) {
    return games[gameNumber].playerList[playerPos];
}
```

Instead this is how you return the full array as a getter

```
function getPlayerListInGame(uint gameNumber) external returns (address[] memory player) {
        address[] memory playerListTmp = new address[](idToGame[gameNumber].playerList.length);
        for (uint i=0; i<idToGame[gameNumber].playerList.length; i++) {
            playerListTmp[i] = idToGame[gameNumber].playerList[i];
        }
        return playerListTmp;
    }
```

If you want the full array, you need first to generate a memory array (that needs to be initialized with the length of the array in storage). Then you loop on each element, copying item-by-item in the memory array, and you finally return it.

**Side Note**: Why do you save the `game` element both in `idToGame` and `games`? In this way, every edit needs to be duplicated. Better to have a single `games` array, while `idToGame` should be a `mapping(uint => uint)` that tells the position of a generic game within the `games` array.

Comment: Hi, thank you for taking the time to write this out - I really appreciate it! 
I implemented your solution and there are no errors or anything, but when I try to render the Game struct to the corresponding index, it simply ignores that the array was created, even after I push msg.sender. I'll continue this response as an edit to my original post:

Comment: I've seen your edit. What's the address expected in your array? Is it `0x0de0b...`? Cause in the `console.log` you posted as an image, those values are there. See my edited answer to understand how to get those elements

Comment: Hi, there, going to make another edit to my question - it doesn't look like the getter is working correctly, but I followed the guide you had provided (from what I can tell) correctly - but I must be missing something. Will put the getter up there. Thank you again!

Comment: edited the answer @TakingJester766 , with an example of how the getter should be implemented, both to get a single element, or the whole array of players. If your array of players is made by a high number of players (like > 100), think of a different way of storing them, as the loop is going to increase the time to extract them.

Answer (score 0):

*(Moving answer material to the answer space on behalf of the question author)*.

I'm happy to say I have finally coded in both pushing to array within the struct, as well as in getting that information! For anyone who in the future wants to see how I did it, this is my code:

The Game struct:

```
struct Game {
    address host; // Establishes host function access 0
    uint gameId; // Allows different games to be played concurrently 1
    uint buyinRequirement; // To establish minimum buyin amount for a game 2
    uint etherWithdrawalReqs; // Tracks # of ether in total from requests. If >/< than contract balance, throws error 3   
    uint gamePot; // Tracks how much ether is in the game's pot 4 
    uint8 tableWithdrawalReqs; // Tracks how many players have requested a withdrawal 5
    uint8 playerCount; // Tracks # of of players in a game 6
    uint8 verifiedWithdrawalReqs; // Tracks # of verifs that withdrawal requests are valid 7
    bool endedBuyin; // Host function to end buyin stage 8
    bool isActive; // Checks if game struct is already done 9 
    address[] playerList; // 10
}
```

The buyin function:

```
function startGame(string memory name, uint buyinReq) public payable isNotInGame {     
    require(initFee == .001 ether, "In order to prevent spam games that never resolve, each game initialization will cost  ether.");
    addFeesPending();
    playerInfo[msg.sender] = Player(name, gameNumber, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, true);
    address[] memory add;
    idToGame[gameNumber] = Game(msg.sender, gameNumber, buyinReq, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, true, add);
    idToGame[gameNumber].playerList.push(msg.sender);
    games.push(idToGame[gameNumber]);
    incGameNumber();
}
```

The getter function (solved from [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3609/returning-a-struct-and-reading-via-web3/101745#101745) previous question asked on Stack Overflow. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwlgp.png) is the image as well).

```
function getGameInfo(uint id) public view returns (Game memory) {
    return idToGame[id];
}
```